# Solved , open problems and levels of difficulty

Tags: problem-solving

What are the advantages and wins of solving already solved problems? Does it help me know how to become better at problem solving and test my abilities on it? Does it help me become better and have more possibilities of solving open problems?

When i find already solved problems difficult to solve, should i look at the answer? Should i try to solve them by reading the theory from books or something else like leave them for some time like one, two or three days and come back to solve them?

I am an undergraduate student who tries to get his degree in math and i am interested in solving open problems.

Thank you.

Comment: Open problems are usually open because they were too hard for any mathematician to solve. Some open problems are out of the way things that no one has tried to solve, so that's not always true.

But you learn math by solving problems, and you will need to work your way up in difficulty. So yes, you will need to solve lots and lots of problems that others have solved.

If you are stuck, it's fine to look at solutions and learn from them. And then try the same problem again later.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are any number of equally valid opinion-based answers.  Questions on SE sites should permit authoritative answers which can be backed by evidence, rather than gut feeling or opinion.